# Java require Constructor and super but i have defined already

Tags: java

This is Waffle.java, it's completed success after compiled.

```
public class Waffle extends Customer{

    int waffle_favourite;
    double amount1;

       static double Waffle(int waffle_favourite, double amount1){

if(waffle_favourite == 1){
     System.out.println("You have picked CHOCHOLATE.");
     System.out.println("The price is RM0.80.");
         amount1 = 0.80;
         return amount1;}

    else if(waffle_favourite == 2){
     System.out.println("You have picked HONEY.");
     System.out.println("The price is RM1.00.");
         amount1 = 1.00;
         return amount1;}

    else if(waffle_favourite == 3){
     System.out.println("You have picked YOGURT.");
     System.out.println("The price is RM1.50.");
         amount1 = 1.50;
         return amount1;}

    else{
     System.out.println("Invalid value.");}return amount1;}}
```

This is Waffle2.java. CMD was required Constructor but i have build in Waffle.java already. How can I solve it??

```
import java.util.Scanner;

   public class Waffle2 extends Waffle{

   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

   int waffle_state;
   double amount2;
   double total_amount;
   double payment;

   public Waffle2(int waffle_favourite, double amount1, int waffle_state, double amount2, double total_amount){
   super(waffle_favourite, amount1);

    if(waffle_state == 1){
         System.out.println("");
     System.out.println("You have picked SOFT.");
     System.out.println("The price is RM1.00.");
         amount2 = 1.00;
         total_amount = amount1 + amount2;
         System.out.println("Your total amount is:RM " + total_amount);  
         System.out.println("");

for(int i=0; i <= 1; i++){

    System.out.print("Please keyin your payment:RM");
    payment = scan.nextDouble();

    if(payment < total_amount){
      total_amount -= payment;

     System.out.println("You still need to pay RM:" + total_amount);}  

    else if(payment == total_amount){
         System.out.println("Thank you for your order.");
             break;}            
else{
         System.out.println("Invalid value.");}}}

    else if(waffle_state == 2){
         System.out.println("");
     System.out.println("You have picked CRISPY.");
     System.out.println("The price is RM1.20.");
         amount2 = 1.20;
         total_amount = amount1 + amount2;
         System.out.println("Your total amount is:RM " + total_amount);
         System.out.println("");

    for(int i=0; i <= 1; i++){

    System.out.print("Please keyin your payment:RM");
    payment = scan.nextDouble();

    if(payment < total_amount){
      total_amount -= payment;

     System.out.println("You still need to pay RM:" + total_amount);}  

    else if(payment == total_amount){
         System.out.println("Thank you for your order.");
             break;}            
else{
         System.out.println("Invalid value.");}}}
    else if(waffle_state == 3){
         System.out.println("");
     System.out.println("You have picked CHEWY.");
     System.out.println("The price is RM1.50.");
         amount2 = 1.50;
         total_amount = amount1 + amount2;
         System.out.println("Your total amount is:RM " + total_amount);
         System.out.println("");

    for(int i=0; i <= 1; i++){

    System.out.print("Please keyin your payment:RM");
    payment = scan.nextDouble();

    if(payment < total_amount){
      total_amount -= payment;

     System.out.println("You still need to pay RM:" + total_amount);}  

    else if(payment == total_amount){
         System.out.println("Thank you for your order.");
             break;}            
else{
         System.out.println("Invalid value.");}}}}}
```

I have compiled this class, after compiled comes out this message
cannot find symbol
symbol : constructor Waffle(int, double)
location: class Waffle
super(waffle_favourite, amount1);
^
1 error

I have try many way, but still happen error, thx for **HELP**.

Comment: don't post your code as image

Comment: `Waffle` doesn't have a constructor. That's a static method.

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

`Waffle` doesn't have a constructor, other than the default, no-arg constructor. This:

```
static double Waffle(int waffle_favourite, double amount1){
```

isn't a constructor. You can tell that because a) it's `static`, b) it's got a return type; constructors have neither.

As such, you can't invoke `super(waffle_favourite, amount1);`, because there is no such constructor. The only thing you can invoke there is `super()`, but you never need to invoke that explicitly. You can invoke `Waffle.Waffle(waffle_favourite, amount1)`, if you want, though.

But it doesn't even look like a constructor, anyway: constructors *construct* the instance. You're not constructing anything, you're just doing things with the parameters. This is just a method.

`Waffle2` *does* have a constructor, syntactically, but again, it's not doing things which are related to constructing a `Waffle2` instance: you're accessing the member variables, but it's not clear why, rather than just using member variables. At the end of a constructor, the invariants of the `Waffle2` class should be established, as in, the rules which make this `Waffle2` "valid" should be true. Are there actually any such rules? If not, you don't actually need a constructor.